# How to store an api key safely, template file

Tags: php, api, security

I never used api calls before, so perhaps this is a dumb question
But i want to use an api call in an template. (basicly, what it will do is check the current price of a product and output that)

Now for using and storing the api key. Would adding this to the template file be unsafe?
If so, what would be a proper way to do this?

```
$key = 123456789
geturl.com?apikey=$key
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not store them in a file in the code-base, this is just asking for people to impersonate you.

This is unsafe because a) someone could look at the source code for a page and have your keys, and b) if this is in a code repository then someone could just search for apiKey and have yours and everyone else's - your key has been compromised without someone even knowing about your website.

Instead, you should store this in an [environment variable](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-keep-your-secret-keys-safe-secure-8b1a7877d69c), or [encrypt the data](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-securely-store-api-keys-4ff3ea19ebda/) in a file - and I've linked some articles to help you in doing one of those.

Comment: Thank you,  reading through them atm

For point A, the api key should never be in the source page with that right?  It would be php that executes on the server side, it uses the api, stores the result and outputs the price of that. so the actual html output would just be the price

Comment: Fair enough, but there's only a single typo separating your PHP code from executing or being displayed as plain text, for example. Whether a typo in your code, possibly exposing your key via an error message, or a typo in an Apache/whatever config file.